Запрет уменьшения элементов css/js
Возможно ли сделать так, что бы при открытии сайта на устройстве с экраном менее 900px по ширине, элементы сайта больше не могли сжиматься и появлялся горизонтальный скролл?

Установите контейнеру min-width: 900px

Этот вопрос похож на: Как задать минимальную ширину окна браузера CSS?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Интересно зачем такое нужно вообще, наоборот хороший верстальщик сделает, что бы всё сжималось вплоть до 320px

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 900px;
}

